# Как сделать подобный градиентный бордер?

Tags: html, css, frontend, градиент

Как сделать подобный border, слегка размытый, с :bofore :after?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это то, что получилось, по идее, это neomorphism
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это как нужно

Comment: Это делается не бордером. Делается обвертка которому задается фон градиентом. А дальше в нем уже блок с белым фоном и контентом.

Comment: это я так и сделал, размытие не получается